# Session null when performning multiple ajax calls

Tags: c#, ajax, session

Please help as this has been driving me nuts since last week and I'm still not closer to a solution...

Environment: IIS 7.5, .Net 4.0, jQuery (latest)

I have an internal web service that I call to create a hierarchy object consisting of a number of customers and their relations. In my web service I store the hierarchy object in `HttpContext.Current.Session`.

Shortly there after in my javascript I loop over the customers visible to the user. For each customer I call an $.ajax function that calls another procedure in my web service. In the C# code I read my hierarchy object from `HttpContext.Current.Session` and using linq reads the data for the current customer.

My problem is that `HttpContext.Current.Session["hierarchy"]` returns null for some customers. It's not the same customers each time even though I'm calling the exact same url.

I have tried reading the hierarchy from `HttpContext.Current.Session` immediately after writing it just to verify that everything in my hierarchy object is actually written to `HttpContext.Current.Session`.

I have tried logging `HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionId` to verify that the session is the same and everything adds up.

I have tried with and without `EnableSessionState` in my Default.apsx

Thanks in advance to anyone who can guide me in the right direction...

./CJ

Answer (score 2):

Is your web service made of WCF? If so, there is no session at all unless asp.net compatibility mode is enabled.

Comment: It's WCF yes. And I have aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true".

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an ASMX web service (hopefully not) be sure to have the following above each method:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

Otherwise, Xing is correct concerning WCF. I know from experience that the session will return null if you do not manually turn on ASP.NET sessions.

Comment: It's not an asmx. It's an svc. I have tried including the WebMethod attribute without any luck :-( It's not that my (Hierarchy)HttpContext.Current.Session["hierarchy"] returns null every time. It's only about 20% of the time. Also I should mention that my code works flawlessly locally and on the test environment. It's the pre-production environment that's causing the trouble.

Comment: @user1480182 So is it 20% of your customers that are returning null all the time or are all of your customers returning null 20% of the time? The session could be expiring too soon if there is not a service call within the allotted expiration time frame.

Comment: If I loop over eg 10 customers then a couple of times I will get null returned from (Hierarchy)HttpContext.Current.Session["hierarchy"]. Some times two of the customers will get null from (Hierarchy)HttpContext.Current.Session["hierarchy"] but sometimes four or five will...